# getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, macros

am using jacob jar for calling a macro of excel sheet from java code..

```
final  ActiveXComponent excel = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");
final Dispatch workbooks = excel.getProperty("Workbooks") .toDispatch();
final Dispatch workBook = Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Open", file.getAbsolutePath()).toDispatch(); 

com.jacob.com.Variant f = new com.jacob.com.Variant(true);
Dispatch.call(workBook, "Close", f);
```

and also am using maven to add all the jar dependency. but then i realised that i need to add the .DLL file then i added jacob jar manually and gave dll file in native library but now am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jacob.com.Dispatch.call(Lcom/jacob/com/Dispatch;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;
        at com.common.getData.callMacro(getData.java:650)
        at com.testcases.PathAndAction.testScreen(PathAndAction.java:874)
        at com.testcases.MainTestClass.testScreen(MainTestClass.java:54)
        at com.testcases.MainTestClass.main(MainTestClass.java:15)
```

Answer (score 3):

This could mean that at runtime, the version of the jar you're using with `com.jacob.com.Dispatch` is different than the one `com.common.getData` was compiled against.  It's telling you that the class `com.jacob.com.Dispatch` does exist but that it has no method named `call` that takes  `Dispatch, String, Object` as arguments.

Are you perhaps compiling with one jar but running with another?

Comment: Yeah, there are a couple of other scenarios that can cause the exception, but it usually means that there is a version mismatch between the jar used for compile and the jar used for running.

Comment: What would the other scenarios be?

Comment: I'm trying to remember -- they were introduced ca 1.2 or 1.3, and I'm thinking it was when the details of inheritance for interfaces changed and it became possible to have a class implement an interface without all of the methods.  Or something to that effect.  But Sun muddled things up quite a bit at that time, so my memory is vague.

Comment: Is it possible you're thinking of `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` or its parent `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` ? Those are also indicative of encountering different versions of class dependencies at runtime than compilation time, but those are from JDK1.0 and they are distinct scenarios from `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.  If you do think of them, please do post... my memory may not be so good either.

Comment: It's been a long time.  We had to make our JVM match the errors the Sun one threw out, to pass the JCK, and, frankly, often they did not really make sense.  But pretty sure there were cases where you would have expected one of the first two and gotten the third.